# How to check that we have read all messages from MQ

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, jmstemplate

need your help with updating the following code,currently this code fetches the first msg from IBM MQ ,but my requirement is to fetch until MQ is empty

```
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

public JmsTemplate getJmsTemplate() {
    return jmsTemplate;
}

@Autowired
public void setJmsTemplate(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
    this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
}

public String onMessage() throws JMSException, IOException {        

    Message source = jmsTemplate.receive("LQ.SCCO4313");

    BytesMessage bm = (BytesMessage) source;

    byte[] byteArr = new byte[(int) bm.getBodyLength()];
    bm.readBytes(byteArr); 

    String msg = new String(byteArr, "UTF-8");  

    logger.info("Message " + msg);
    logger.info("MESSAGE received from myMessageQueue ");
    return msg;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A JMS MessageConsumer's *receive()* or *receiveNoWait()* would return with null where there is no message in a queue. There will be an exception if there is any internal error.

So you can check for `source == null` in your code.

Comment: I can check for null but how long would it fetch for?

Comment: Till the last message in the queue is browsed.